# how do I declare leastfreq in scope?

Tags: c++

Here in the code, I have created a function to calculate the least frequent element. Whenever I run the program it says leastfreq was not declared in the scope.
Can someone tell me how to solve this error and what is this error about?
Error : "error: 'leastfreq' was not declared in this scope"

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,i;
    cout<<"Enter the value of n:";
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Enter element "<<i<<":";
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    leastfreq(a,n);
}

int leastfreq(int a[],int arrsize){
   int currentct,leastct=0;
   int leastelm;
   for(int j=0;j<arrsize;j++){
       int temp = a[j];
   for(int i=0;i<arrsize;i++){
        if(a[i]=temp){
            currentct++;
        }
        if(currentct<leastct){
            currentct = leastct;
            leastelm = a[j];
       }
   }
   }
   return leastelm;
}
```

Comment: change order of `leastfreq` and `main` or declare function by adding `int leastfreq(int a[],int arrsize);` before `main`. In C++ order of symbols defined is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**: Put the function `leastfreq`'s definition before `main()` as shown below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//leastfreq defined before main
int leastfreq(int a[],int arrsize){
   int currentct,leastct=0;
   int leastelm;
   for(int j=0;j<arrsize;j++){
       int temp = a[j];
   for(int i=0;i<arrsize;i++){
        if(a[i]=temp){
            currentct++;
        }
        if(currentct<leastct){
            currentct = leastct;
            leastelm = a[j];
       }
   }
   }
   return leastelm;
}
int main(){
    int n,i;
    cout<<"Enter the value of n:";
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Enter element "<<i<<":";
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    leastfreq(a,n);
}
```

**Solution 2**: Added a function declaration for `leastfreq` before `main()` as shown below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//added declaration for `leastfreq`
int leastfreq(int a[],int arrsize);
int main(){
    int n,i;
    cout<<"Enter the value of n:";
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Enter element "<<i<<":";
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    leastfreq(a,n);
}

int leastfreq(int a[],int arrsize){
   int currentct,leastct=0;
   int leastelm;
   for(int j=0;j<arrsize;j++){
       int temp = a[j];
   for(int i=0;i<arrsize;i++){
        if(a[i]=temp){
            currentct++;
        }
        if(currentct<leastct){
            currentct = leastct;
            leastelm = a[j];
       }
   }
   }
   return leastelm;
}
```